# Download files from Google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Can any one please tell me how to download or read the files from Google cloud storage without login/Authentication

when i tried the below link i am getting

https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/igvideos/o/test1235.txt

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

Thanks

Thanigaivelan

Comment: change the permissions on the bucket to allow all?

Comment: Is the object set to public-read?